# Finiteness of the dimension of a normed space and compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

I am studying functional analysis, and in the setting of normed spaces
I have seen the theorem that states that the unit ball is compact
iff the space is finite dimensional.

I also saw an exercise:

> Let $X$ be finite dimensional, prove that for any non-empty and closed
>   $C$, $x\in C$ there exist $c\in C$ s.t $||x-c||=d(x,C)$.

The proof started with:

> take $c\in C$ and consider  $$ D=\overline{B(x,||x-c||)}\cap C $$
>
> $D$ is closed and bounded hence, since $X$ is finite dimensional, is
>   compact.

I would be glad if someone could help me with the following two questions:

1) It seems that the theorem I read about the compactness also extends
to $X$ is finite dimensional iff $\{x,||x-x_{0}||\leq d\}$ is compact
for any $x_{0}\in X,d\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$. is this correct ?

2) $C$ is closed, $\overline{B(x,||x-c||)}$ is also closed, hence
so is the intersection. since $\overline{B(x,||x-c||)}$ is bounded
then so is the intersection.

And so I get that $D$ is closed and bounded. Why can't I conclude
that $D$ is compact without the assumption that $X$ is finite dimensional
?

Comment: Closed and bounded is not the same thing as compact in...well...infinite dimensions! The Heine-Borel theorem is truly a theorem about $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a lemma by Riesz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma), which states the following:

> Let $X$ be a normed vector space, $U\subsetneq X$ a proper subspace, $\epsilon> 0$. Then there is $x \in X$ with $\|x\| = 1$ and ${\rm dist}(x, U) \ge 1 -\epsilon$.

If $X$ is infinite dimensional, you can use this Lemma with $\epsilon = \frac 12$ inductively to construct a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $\|x_n\| = 1$ and $\|x_n - x_m\| \ge \frac 12$ for all $n \ne m$. Obviously $(x_n)$ cannot have any Cauchy subsequence. So the closed ball $\{x\in X \mid \|x\| \le 1\}$ is not compact.

The equivalence "compact $\iff$ closed and bounded" holds exactly iff $X$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Could be worth noting that "compact $\implies$ closed and bounded" remains true even in infinite dimension.